# In single page how to create Account list, records need to show in below columns AccountName, Total number of contacts on Account

Tags: apex, visualforce, design-patterns

```
public class wrapperClassController1 {

public List<aAccount> AccountList {get; set;}
public integer ccount {get; set;}
public List<aAccount> getAccounts() {
    if(AccountList == null) {
        AccountList = new List<aAccount>();
        //ccount = [SELECT count() FROM Contact WHERE AccountId =:AccountList.Id];   
        for(Account a: [select Id, Name from Account limit 50]) {

            for(Contact c:[SELECT count() FROM Contact WHERE AccountId =:a.Id]){
               ccount = c;
            }

            System.debug('ccount-->'+ccount);
            AccountList.add(new aAccount(a,ccount));
        }
    }
    System.debug('AccountList-->'+AccountList);
    return AccountList;
}

public class aAccount {
    public Account acc {get; set;}
    public integer ccount {get; set;}

    public aAccount(Account a,integer ccount) {
        acc = a;
        ccount = ccount;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How to questions should be avoided here, please show some effort and if you are not sure where to start, I would recommend doing trailheads, we will be more than happy to help once you have tried on your own and updated your post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this will be to use one of this options on this post: 
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000ZoV3QAK

The idea is to use one of those options put the number of contacts in one custom field (*Total_Contacts__c*) on the Account object. 
After that is done you don't need a custom controller or a controller extension, you can use a page like this one.

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Account List">
    <apex:form id="theForm">
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:dataTable var="a" value="{!accounts}" border="1" cellpadding="3" columns="3">

             <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!a.name}"/>
             <apex:column headerValue="Phone" value="{!a.phone}"/>
             <apex:column headerValue="Phone" value="{!a.Total_Contacts__c}"/>

            </apex:dataTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:panelGrid columns="2">
                <apex:commandLink action="{!previous}">Previous </apex:commandLink>
                <apex:commandLink action="{!next}"> Next</apex:commandLink>
            </apex:panelGrid>

    </apex:form>
</apex:pageBlock>
```